# CollectionView ThresholdReachedCommand fired before loading complete

Tags: visual-studio, maui, collectionviewsource

Has a question regarding CollectionView in MAUI.
So, I have CollectionView wrapped to RefreshView.

```
<RefreshView Grid.Row="1"
             Command="{Binding RefreshSearchCommand}"
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Requests}" x:Name="RequestCollection"
                RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
                RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreDataCommand}">
    <CollectionView.Footer>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
    </CollectionView.Footer>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:GetRquestsAndUser">
            <Cntr:ReqSinglPanel
                CurrentRequest="{Binding .}"
                Padding="0,5,5,5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView> </RefreshView>
```

Also, have a RelayCommand for RefreshView

```
    public void RefreshSearch()
    {
        if (IsLoading)
            return;
        page = 0;
        Requests.Clear();
        try
        {
            Search();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ...... }
        finally {
            IsBusy = false;
            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

And RelayCommand for CollectionView

```
public void LoadMoreData()
        {
            if (IsLoading || IsBusy)
                return;           
            try { 
                IsLoading = true;
                Search();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { .... }
            finally { IsLoading = false; }
        }
```

So, on screen load, I set refreshView in load mode `IsBusy=true`. It goes through the Search() and load data into `public ObservableCollection<GetRquestsAndUser> Requests`
But before the data appear in collectionView it has enough delay to fire `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand`  and go through the loading process again, load extra data, and even double already loaded data(don't know yet how).

Actually, the same happens when RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand fires the normal way, it sets IsLoading=false and fires yourself again because RemainingItemsThreshold is still lower than 1.

Is it a possible way to prevent such behavior? Or might be another way to make it work properly?

I'm thinking to get rid of (RefreshView) / (Threshold part of CollectionView), but not sure (how to implement the "pull up to refresh" functionality only with CollectionView) / (dynamic loading only with RefreshView)

UDP:

```
Search code
public void Search()
        {
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try{
                        Global.searchModel.Page = page;
                        SearchResult = await _restService.PostGetRquestsAndUser(Global.searchModel);                  
                        foreach(GetRquestsAndUser req in SearchResult.Result)
                            Requests.Add(req);
                        SearchCountStr = string.Format("{0} out of {1}", Requests.Count.ToString(), SearchResult.SearchCount.ToString());
                        page++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {}
                });
        }
```

Comment: I this android?

Comment: Testing on Android yes, but coding in VisualStudio aiming to Android+IOS.

Comment: May I see "Search()" code?

Comment: Edit the Question body. I guess you suspect incorrect use of async? It just hit my mind. SHould I make RelayCommand async instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will have to write this here, because it is gonna be long.

First, yes. It makes sense for the command to be async. At least all my communications are done in such commands, and are awaited.

Second, ObservableCollection is terrible class for what you are doing. One of the first things that I do, is make RangeObservableCollection, that allows me to modify the list of items, without raising notifications for every item. (Usually, I either block notifications, and allow them after the adding is done, with internal check if any modifications have been done... or I simply add Silent methods, that modify the Items. AddSilent and AddRangeSilent for examle..)

Third. Your clearing of the collection, makes no sense. It is a loop. Add Items > Go to the end > Clear Items > Add Items > Go to the end ...

This command should be used for loading more items , when you detect you are reaching the end. Not for resetting all at the beginning.

In fact, your idea for "pull to refresh" is the most common approach to solve your problem. And your users are familiar with it. Just go for it.

Comment: Im cleaning the collection only when the user reaches the top of the list and pulls up to refresh all the data ( RefreshSearch() ). When the user just scrolls it down I dynamically load new extra data in the same collection ( LoadMoreData() ). Thx for the advice, i try it an it message how it works;)

Comment: Yes, it feels like it works much smoother, and don't see doubled data anymore. What i did: 1) change collection as RangeObservableCollection(and all changes related to this of course) 2) make the command async by yourself. 3) Move the "Search" code to the command method bodies. Obviously, because one command fully replaces the data range another command just Adds extra data. Thank you for your analysis.